# Como detener un ciclo for y retornar un valor - java

Tags: java

Tengo un método que recibe una lista, y todos los datos de esa lista se deben insertar en la base de datos:

```
public Boolean insertar(final List<SubespecialidadMuestra> subespecialidadesMuestras) {
    try {
        final Subespecialidad subespecialidad = subespecialidadesMuestras.get(0).getSubespecialidad();
        final Especialidad especialidad = subespecialidad.getEspecialidad();
        
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERTAR_SUBESPECIALIDAD, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        statement.setInt(1, especialidad.getCodigoEspecialidad());
        statement.setString(2, subespecialidad.getSubespecialidadNombre());
        statement.setInt(3, subespecialidad.getSubespecialidadEstado());
        
        if (statement.executeUpdate() == 1) {
            resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
            resultSet.next();
            final int CODIGO_SUBESPECIALIDAD = resultSet.getInt(1);
            MuestraBiologica muestraBiologica;
            
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERTAR_SUBESPECIALIDADES_MUESTRAS);
            for (final SubespecialidadMuestra subespecialidadMuestra : subespecialidadesMuestras) {
                muestraBiologica = subespecialidadMuestra.getMuestraBiologica();
                statement.setInt(1, CODIGO_SUBESPECIALIDAD);
                statement.setInt(2, muestraBiologica.getCodigoMuestraBiologica());

                if (statement.executeUpdate() != 1) {
                    connection.rollback();
                    break;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            connection.commit();
            return true;
        } else {
            connection.rollback();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (final SQLException sqlException) {
        System.err.println("Error en SQLEspecialidad - Insertar: " + sqlException.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
            statement.close();
            } catch (final SQLException sqlException) {
                Logger.getLogger(SQLCuenta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqlException);
            }
        }
        
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                if (!resultSet.isClosed()) {
                    resultSet.close();
                }
            } catch (final SQLException sqlException) {
                Logger.getLogger(SQLCuenta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqlException);
            }
        }
        
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (final SQLException sqlException) {
                Logger.getLogger(SQLCuenta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqlException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dentro del ciclo for, tengo un operador `if` que se encarga de verificar si se inserto una fila o no, si el valor devuelto de `executeUpdate()` es diferente de 1, el ciclo `for` debe detenerse(break) y retornar un valor `false`, pero no me deja poner el `break` y el `return` juntos, solo debo poner uno de ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que tienes que hacer, es usar una variable booleana:

```
    boolean rowsInserted = true;
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERTAR_SUBESPECIALIDADES_MUESTRAS);
    for (final SubespecialidadMuestra subespecialidadMuestra: subespecialidadesMuestras) {
        muestraBiologica = subespecialidadMuestra.getMuestraBiologica();
        statement.setInt(1, CODIGO_SUBESPECIALIDAD);
        statement.setInt(2, muestraBiologica.getCodigoMuestraBiologica());

        if (statement.executeUpdate() != 1) {
            rowsInserted = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!rowsInserted) {
        connection.rollback();
        return false;
    }

    connection.commit();
    return true;
```